# Graph API: Get Sharepoint drive item by id if drive is unknown

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I added a sharepoint file browser to my app using MS Graph API to enumerate document libraries/folder/files. When selecting a file I get a driveitem id, a drive id and a webUrl (and of course many other properties).

I would like to store a reference to the selected file in a safe way: If a file is moved to another library (on same site collection) or renamed, the reference should still be valid.

I guess for office type files, I could use the webUrl, because it is a durable link and does not change. For other file types, a file can be identified by combination of driveid and itemid and queried in graph api like 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{my_site}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}`

If I rename a file, the item id is not changed. That's great.

If I move a file to another library, the item id is also not changed, but the drive id changes. I didn't find a way to query for a drive id across all drives on a site collection. Is it possible? Or is my approch wrong?

If the document id feature was enabled on the site collection, I could probably use this id to identify a file. But I cannot guarantee that (and I also don't know how to search by document id in Graph API).

P.S. If there is a better way to access files by id in CSOM, I could also use this instead of Graph API...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title, if you are using the Graph REST API, you can use the GET DriveItem endpoint:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}
```

Only the siteId and itemId are required.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http